# Join 2 flat files with different columns in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to join together two excel (or csv) files in Power BI. These files are completely different (except for the key I want to join on). They also have a different granularity.

Main File:

| Company | SalesTeam | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |

Sales Team:

| SalesTeam | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Billy Jean | Loverville |
| 1 | Elvis | Memphis |
| 2 | Bart S. | Springfield |

So, I want to join these files together, then have a drill-through from the Main File to the Sales Team. I'm thinking it's not possible since all the tutorials expect the files to have the same basic layout - more like combining them or unioning them but not joining them in a database way.

If I can't do a "join", is there another approach I should take to be able to drill-through into some detail? I've never used Power Query before but wondering if that is an option.

Comment: I'm not following what the issue or ask is. Why do you want to join vs having a relationship in the data model? If you do want to join, then why not merge the Main File into the Sales Team?

Comment: It's a problem with granularity. It's not a perfect analogy, but think of a Order Header and Order Detail (where the detail just has the order name and not the values). I'd like to show the order header and drill into the order detail. I only have spreadsheets to use, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: In Power BI, keep the tables separate, and then create a relationship between the two based on the `SalesTeam` column. It is common to have different granularities and table structures in PBI that are related to one another. It is the visualization that provides the insights, not the table/data view in PBI.

Comment: @SamNseir This is the solution. Can you create answer and I'll mark it that way? I think I queried it wrong, which is why I didn't see it originally (used "Join" vs. "Relationship").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power BI, keep the tables separate, and then create a relationship between the two based on the `SalesTeam` column. It is common to have different granularities and table structures in PBI that are related to one another.

It is the visualization that provides the insights, not the table/data view in PBI.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the second table so there is a single drill down for each SalesTeam

[image]

An M/PowerQuery method to get there is

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"Name", "Location"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"SalesTeam"}, {{"NameLocation", each  Text.Combine([Merged], " | "), type text}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```